# nightmare js white screen in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, nightmare

I tried and learn nightmarejs, when I run the example duckduckgo the output in electron is just white screen
I hope I can learn or get some experience form here

version windows 10 64bit
"nightmare": "^3.0.2"

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({show: true});

nightmare
  .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
  .type('#search_form_input_homepage', 'github nightmare')
  .click('#search_button_homepage')
  .wait('#r1-0 a.result__a')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#r1-0 a.result__a').href)
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```

[image: output electron white screen]